# How do you make a java quiz?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How would you make a java quiz where if you get the answer wrong then no more questions appear eg

Do you want to eat me?

Person types in Yes, then the command prompt doesn't show the next question but if the person said no then the next question appeared? I have figured out how to make the questions with the arguments however when the wrong answer is typed it shows the next question.

So how would I make it like

Do you want to eat me?

Person : Yes

Please close this window or press any key.

But if the person said No it would say - Can you fly then ask that question etc
This is the code I have so far,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String fail = "Thank you for your time, please close this window.";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("You have entered the fast track to becoming a MI6   Intelligence Officer.");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
System.out.println("(All questions are to be answered with 'Yes' or 'No')");

String a = input.next();

if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
    System.out.println("true");
}
else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    System.out.println(fail);
}
else{
    System.out.println("ERROR - You typed " + a + " this is incorrect,   please type 'Yes' or 'No'");
 }
System.out.println("Do you want to protect this country?");
String e = input.next();

if(e.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
    System.out.println("true");
}
else if(e.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    System.out.println(fail);

}
else{
    System.out.println("ERROR - You typed " + e + " this is incorrect,   please type 'Yes' or 'No'");
 }
 }
```

*So basically the problem is that when I type in the wrong answer it displays the next question, I would like it to display no more questions after the wrong answer.*

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Well, one problem seems to be that he hasn't read [ask].

Comment: This is pretty basic logic processes. My suggestion is to practice the language and build up the confidence to take a stab at the projects that pop into your head. Once you run into a problem with your code, we'd be more than happy to address your problems. If you *have* taken a stab at the code, you need to show it to us - we're not mind readers.

Comment: I dont want to eat you

Comment: without code how can we solve your problem??

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the problem clear enough, just to let you know the eat me question was the first thing that popped into my head when I was trying to explain this

Comment: Sorry for not showing my code, I have added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a basic loop (while, do-while, for) and place a break statement whenever you want to immediately exit the loop.  An unlabled break statement will exit out of the innermost loop.  As an example:

```
boolean complete = false;
do{
    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
        System.out.println(fail);
        break;
    }
    //Additional questions follow similar format
}while(!complete)
```

The advantage here is that you do not exit the program immediately, allowing you to further work with your program outside the loop. For instance, you could keep track of the boolean variable and use it outside the loop to write a customized "Goodbye" message depending on if the user got through the full quiz correctly, or did not pass the quiz (for example, another if/else statement based on the boolean after the loop will allow you to move every line of "System.out.println(fail);" to one line at the end).

Comment: Might as well have a `while(true)` since you don't actually use `complete` elsewhere and `break` out of it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils The example of `complete` is something the OP can build upon if they want (in theory).  Thanks for the initialization catch.

Comment: I have thought about it today and I don't think this would be the best option as I just wanted something simple and I was totally over thinking it I mainly wanted something to exit it which is why I used the System.exit(0)